# Relationship between Conditional R squared and random effect variance?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have run a simple lmer with one fixed effect (day) and 3 random effects (athlete, infusion and sport). Model below.

`fit <-lmer(log(sfer) ~ day + (1|infusion) + (1|athlete) + (1|sport))`

I am really interested in the influence of these random effects. The marginal R2 is 47.9%, and the conditional R2 80.72%. So if I understand correctly, the inclusion of these 3 random effects have increased the explanatory power of the model by ~33%.

The output related to the random effects of the model is below

```
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
  athlete  (Intercept) 0.18875  0.4345  
  sport    (Intercept) 0.00000  0.0000  
  infusion (Intercept) 0.03043  0.1744  
  Residual             0.12879  0.3589
```

I can see that majority of the variance was accounted for by athlete, with very little infusion or sport.

How can I report this within a scientific paper? does the 0.12879 of the residual variance equate to the ~20% of the total model that was unexplained (100- conditional R2)? Of the ~33% additional variance explained by including the random effects in the model, is there a way to break this up by each random effect, and show that athlete was the strongest?

Any help, or examples how this may have been done previously would be great!